# Event Grid Trigger Not Firing For Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-eventgrid

My Azure Functions Event Grid trigger is not firing. Here's what I did.

- Key Vault is set-up to report the `Secret New Version Created` event to an EventGrid system topic
- This topic is subscribed by a subscription delivering the events to an Azure Function
- The functions has an Event Grid trigger (see below, default created by portal):

```cs
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid"
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;

public static void Run(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
}
```

I googled, and there is not much more guidance for such an entry-level scenario. What I am thinking about maybe is authorisation... How is the subscription able to trigger the function? In the process (configured via GUI/portal) there was nothing about auth...

Do you have any idea why events are not firing?

Cheers

Comment: Can you see in the portal your subscription? Use the Metrics to see the events. Note, that the emitting event from the *Key vault* source is taking few seconds. Also, you can create  (for test purpose) one more subscription with a storage queue.

Comment: As it turned out I was just too impatient. The delivery of the events took 4 minutes and looking back at the logs I can see the invocations just fine.

Comment: OK, btw. once you can see a deployed subscription on the topic, the event handler authorization has been passed during a validation handshake of the destination  endpoint/resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue  of Azure Functions Event Grid trigger not firing events is resolved after few minutes ,as delivery of the events from the Key vault  source took few minutes to reflect in logs as updated by @baouss.( Use the Metrics to see the events.)

The currently supported events are listed on the Microsoft Docs website, listed under "[Event Grid event schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault#event-grid-event-schema?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-4021705)" for the Key Vault docs.Use the Metrics to see the events.
You can also see [Get notified of changes in Azure Key Vault by using Event Grid](https://zimmergren.net/get-notified-of-changes-in-azure-key-vault-using-event-grid/)  by creating azure storage queue.